# cellForRowAtIndexPath invocation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am developing an ToDoList iOS app that uses table view. Cell contents(UITableCellView)  are filled by a instance variable of nsmutablearray.

When I add a new ToDoItem, the content is being displayed twice for each row I add. When I put a breakpoint and debug the code I found that cellForRowAtIndexPath method is called twice for every row I add. Why is that happening. How to handle this case or is there any other alternative method to return UITableCellView cell for display.

Method is shown below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell;
    cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"ListPrototypeCell"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    ToDoItem *item = [self.toDoItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = item.itemName;
    return cell;
}
```

This method is called when user adds new item

```
-(IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

    AddToDoItemViewController *ITEM = [segue sourceViewController];
    ToDoItem *tItem = ITEM.toDoItem;
    if (tItem!=nil) {
        [self.toDoItems addObject:tItem];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self setItems:self.toDoItems];
    }  
}
```

EDIT:

```
-(void)setItems:(NSMutableArray *)item{
    if (item!=nil) {
        tDItems = item;
    }
}
```

tDItems is just another instance variable I am using
Thanks in advance

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code.

Comment: Please find the code

Comment: What are you returning for numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: I am returning 1. And for numberOfRowsInSection I am returning return [self.toDoItems count]

Comment: I wonder what setItems does.

Comment: @gnasher729 Please ignore that method call. I am using it for some other purpose. That is not affecting the issue what I have mentioned above

Comment: Put a breakpoint after setItems and check the count of your array. If you are passing this method the array, it is relevant.

Comment: We definitely need to see more of your code in order to help out. It would make sense that you are creating duplicate items in your array at some point, but you have stated that you have checked the array and there are no duplicates.

Comment: @JonSetting. When I add first item count shows 1 but when i add second item count shows 3.

Comment: setItems may be the issue then. Can you post its code.

Comment: @AnthonyM That is all the code have been implemented.

Comment: @AnthonyM. I have posted code for setItems method

Comment: Where do you use tDItems?

Comment: Wherever you are adding items to your array, you are somehow, accidentally adding more items. We are going to need way more code than this to help out honestly. I'd need to see the entire view controller and the `AddToDoItemViewController` at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

just check your array if duplicate items are added to the array cause even if cellForRowAtIndexPath is called twice it will not create duplicate cells if items in array are not duplicate. cellForRowAtIndexPath might get called twice because of multiple reloads

Comment: there are no duplicates in my array

Answer (score 0):

i think problem is with the reloading the table data ..try to reload data like this...may be it works

```
-(IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

    AddToDoItemViewController *ITEM = [segue sourceViewController];
    ToDoItem *tItem = ITEM.toDoItem;
    if (tItem!=nil) {
        [self.toDoItems addObject:tItem];
        [self setItems:self.toDoItems];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` with `[ToDoItem addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];`
  where i= indexPath for where you want to insert Element.

`     [tableView beginUpdates];

```
      [insertRowAtIndexArray removeAllObjects];

      [insertRowAtIndexArray addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
      [toDoItems addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];

      i++;


[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertRowAtIndexArray withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic)];

[tableView endUpdates];`
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a small fix and it worked. Below is the code

```
 -(IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

AddToDoItemViewController *ITEM = [segue sourceViewController];
ToDoItem *tItem = ITEM.toDoItem;
if (tItem!=nil) {

    if ([self.toDoItems count] == 0) {    // This is the fix made
       [self.toDoItems addObject:tItem];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self setItems:self.toDoItems];

}
```

}

But I am not sure how the items are getting added from the second item onwards.addObject is working only for the first item and there are no duplicates in the view. But if i remove that if condition then duplicates can be seen. Now I am debugging to see why only it is working for first item.